# NPM revert change in the downloaded package

Tags: npm

I downloaded an npm package in my mac and made a change in one of the html files (index.html), but i now want to revert back to the original initial version, is there a command in npm to do this ?

or should i have to load the package again?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the package again:

```
npm install PACKAGE_NAME
```